# \NewDocumentCommand: Why can't I put args on an own line?

Tags: xparse, arguments

I encountered a peculiarity concerning `\NewDocumentCommand` arguments.
In a case where I had real long names in the arguments, I wanted to put
them each on its own line. The first ones are OK, the 2 last ones are
problematic, as shown in the MWE. Is this the normal behaviour or is it a 
bug or am I doing something stupid?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
%                           12  3        4          56     
\NewDocumentCommand\TestArg{st+ O{\empty}D(){\empty}mD()%
                              {\empty}O{\empty}}{%
%                                     7
\noindent
3: #3 \\
4: #4 \\
5: #5 \\
6: #6 \\
7: #7
}
\begin{document}
\TestArg[Three](Four){Five}(Six)[Seven]
\par\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\TestArg
[Three]
(Four)
{Five}
(Six)
[Seven]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A percent sign at the end of the lines would solve the problem... I guess that this happens because some equivalent of `\@ifnextchar` sees the space at the end of the line instead of the `(` or `[`. I don't know why this doesn't happen for the first ones, though.

Comment: I know that a percent sign solves it, but I wonder whether this is normal.

Comment: I'm uncertain why you would separate `D()` on one line and `{\empty}` on the next. By the way, why `{\empty}` and not `{}`?

Comment: By a precise choice when `xparse` was being developed, optional arguments cannot be on a new line; precisely, there cannot even be a space before them.

Comment: @egreg If you don'y mind explaining, what problem could arise from accepting optional arguments on a new line?

Comment: @egreg: As I said, I had some long names in my arguments, so for clarity I wanted them each on its own line (at the call!).  What speaks against {\empty}?

Comment: @Jack Well, you can't with optional arguments in brackets, that's all. About `{\empty}`, this is not empty.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik see the amsmath package which changes the standard `\@ifnextchar` handling so that `\\ ` newline `[a+b]` in the first array cell of the next line is not misinterpreted as `\\[a+b]` and give an error that a+b isn't a length

Comment: @egreg: 1) Is this retriction only for optional args in brackets? 2) when or why would I use \empty? Never in arguments? If you make your comment to an answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: there is no reason to use `\empty` as the default value of an argument as it just makes things be slower, xparse inserts `\empty` that then expands to nothing, rather than making the default `{}` in which case xparse inserts nothing

Comment: Perhaps worth raising this on the LaTeX-L mailing list: the team have argued back-and-forth about this issue, _e.g._ what is 'expected', what is consistent (think `\item[foo]`), _etc._

Comment: And documenting it in an easy-to-find place would also be helpful. Well, at least it is on SE now:-)

Answer (score 17):

Let's consider a simpler example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\TestArg{mO{x}}{%
  1: #1, 2: #2
}

\begin{document}

\TestArg{a}[b]

\TestArg{a} [b]

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

You can clearly see that in the second case `[b]` is not recognized as an optional argument; instead, the default value `x` is used and `[b]` is printed separately, with a space in front of it.

A new line counts as a space, so it's not a surprise if also

```
\TestArg
{a}
[b]
```

produces the same result.

This was a precise choice when the interface of `xparse` was developed. The team followed the example of `amsmath` that doesn't allow spaces in front of optional arguments to `\\`, because of the infamous

```
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
[1] & [2]
\end{array}\right]
```

that raises an error, because `[1]` is mistaken for the optional argument to `\\`. Instead

```
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
[1] & [2]
\end{bmatrix}
```

works flawlessly.

The input `\TestArg{a} [b]` is deemed ambiguous. There were two choices, the team followed the path of considering `[b]` *not* an optional argument.

You get the same behavior with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\TestArg{mD(){x}}{%
  1: #1, 2: #2
}

\begin{document}

\TestArg{a}(b)

\TestArg{a} (b)

\end{document}
```

---

In my opinion, one should never define macros with seven arguments. In your case two are for the variants, four are optional and one is mandatory.

A key-value interface would be much better:

```
\TestArg[
  var-a=true,
  var-b=false,
  opt-A=Three,
  opt-B=Four,
  opt-C=Six,
  opt-D=Seven,
]{Five}
```

By the way, `{\empty}` does not specify an empty default value: if tested with `\tl_if_empty:nTF{#3}`, a missing first optional argument would make LaTeX follow the false branch.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that it's still not clear (at least to me) if we should have the current behaviour or not: the ``\\`` case is perhaps 'special' and one might argue it should be handled separately from everything else.

Comment: @egreg: What signature would this key-val solution have?

Comment: @Jack That would be `{O{}m}`. Defining the key-value interface requires going into `\ExplSyntaxOn`, but for such complex commands this is really better.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry to bother you again. Can you also show me the body of the command. It is a bit complexer than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: @Jack It would be easier if you show your actual situation, with an example of use and the details about the optional arguments and the variants. Open a new question, please.

Answer (score 9):

you can not have white space before optional arguments that follow the last mandatory argument so this works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
%                           12  3        4          56     
\NewDocumentCommand\TestArg{st+ O{\empty}D(){\empty}mD()%
                              {\empty}O{\empty}}{%
%                                     7
\noindent
3: #3 \\
4: #4 \\
5: #5 \\
6: #6 \\
7: #7
}
\begin{document}
\TestArg[Three](Four){Five}(Six)[Seven]
\par\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\TestArg
[Three]
(Four)
{Five}%
(Six)%
[Seven]
\end{document}
```

This is by design so that (like the optional arguments in `amsmath`) you do not get mis-interpretation in things like

```
.... 25\\
[foo] & 26 \\
```

where `[foo]` is intended to be the data in the array cell, not an argument to `\\`

Answer (score 3):

With the latest release of `xparse`, you will find that the `b` is picked up as you expect. We have refined the treatment of trailing optional arguments such that spaces can be allowed or forbidden:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\TestArgOne{m O{x}}{%
  1: #1, 2: #2
}
\NewDocumentCommand\TestArgTwo{m!O{x}}{%
  1: #1, 2: #2
}

\begin{document}

\TestArgOne{a}[b]

\TestArgOne{a} [b]

\TestArgTwo{a}[b]

\TestArgTwo{a} [b]

\end{document}
```

As you will see,  `\TestArgOne` grabs the `[b]` as an optional argument whether or not there is a space. In contrast, for `\TestArgTwo` I have used the syntax `!O{x}`, where the `!` means that the optional argument *has* to follow immediately with no space. This controllable behaviouris useful as depending on the use case, a space may or may not make sense. (The classic example is `\\[...]`, which is used in math mode and where a space or newline before the `[` means something very different.)