# Weird error : use of [ ] in array

Tags: tables, errors, brackets

thank you for reading.

I was trying to use some commutators in an array when I found this error :

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.  a l.9 [a] A
>   number should have been here; I inserted '0'. (If you can't figure out
>   why I needed to see a number, look up 'weird error' in the index to
>   The TeXbook.)
>
> ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). Dimensions can be in units of
>   em, ex, in, pt, pc, cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a
>   new one! I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
>   To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to delete the
>   erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete two letters. (See Chapter 27
>   of The TeXbook.)
>
> ! Missing = inserted for \ifdim. I was expecting to see '<', '=', or
>   '>'. Didn't.

With the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{array}{c}
first ligne\\
[second ligne]
\end{array}$$

\end{document}
```

The code creates a pdf with some text on the second page and some black space on the right of it. 
It does compute well when you remove the left bracket [, or when you use the brackets on the first ligne.

Is this related with a \\ [ on two consecutive lines ?

Comment: First of all: Don't use `$$...$$`.

Answer (score 3):

The

```
 \\
 [second ligne]
```

is read as  `\\[second ligne]`, which is then interpreted as length specification of additional vertical spacing, consisting of `second ligne` here, which is no length, of course. The main reason for this interpretation is that there is no real line break after `\\` here.

One possible solution: Insert an empty line between `\\` and `[`, if the `[...]` is mandatory for your purpose.

A better solution is to hide the `[]` pair in a macro, this would allow for logical markup in addition.

Side note: Don't use `$$...$$`, since that is deprecated syntax for almost 25 years now. Use `\[...\]` or `$...$` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{c}
first ligne\\

[second ligne]
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Better solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand{\bracketed}[1]{[#1]}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{c}
x^{2}\\
\bracketed{x^{3}}
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the command `\\` can have an optional argument: `\\[<dimen>]`, where `<dimen>` is the vertical space to be skipped.

And when the next line begins with `[`, TeX thinks that what comes after is a dimension, thus the `Missing number, treated as zero`.

You can tell the `\\` command that it doesn't have an optional argument by telling it to `\relax`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{array}{c}
first ligne\\\relax
[second ligne]
\end{array}$$

\end{document}
```

---

egreg recently posted an answer on [why `xparse` doesn't accept optional arguments on a new line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422486/134574), an this is exactly the reason.

Comment: This is basically the same solution as Christian Hupfer's, except that I use a different way to trick TeX. You should accept his answer.

Comment: By refusing to get accepted you won't get to 8888 very soon :-P

Comment: Is this a challenge? I passed you in this month's ranking, hehe ;-)

Comment: Well, I can't sit at my desk all the while (like many seem to do so here) when being in front of students and teaching them ;-) And I've lost some of my supporting voters, since they left TeX.SE... A challenge, no, it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I was just kidding...